# JPA not works when run via executable jar, but works in eclipse

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

When executed in `Eclipse`, it works fine. But when executed via `executable jar` facing the following error
 [image]

Here is the `persistence.xml` file I have been using.

[image]

Following are the pom entries that I am using for JPA
 [image]

If anyone faced the same issue and resolved, please share the ideas. As we need to deliver for testing, any help at earliest would be very helpful.

Comment: persistence.xml under META-INF in the JAR. All requisite jars in the CLASSPATH. That's all there is.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your jar file doesn't include external jar files. Try using the assembly plugin for maven:

[See a description of it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574650/8256197)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this in provider

org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider

Comment: Just before tried. Now its not works even in Eclipse, also in executable jar. Facing the exception. Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named amber

Comment: can you check whether hibernate library files present on your executable jar?